# Why is my view returning an invalid object error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to replicate this query into a view in SQL Server but I keep getting an error. The query runs fine but when I copy and paste into a view I get an error at the bottom end of the query:

> Invalid Object Name 'BVSFWarehouse.dbo.sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY'

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
SELECT
    H.OpportunityID, H.CREATEDDATE, H.STAGENAME AS 'Q1-14 Stage', 
    H.CLOSEDATE AS 'Q1-14 Close Date'
FROM            
    (SELECT  
         OpportunityID, MAX(CREATEDDATE) AS MaxDate
     FROM            
         BVSFWarehouse.dbo.sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY
     WHERE        
         (CREATEDDATE <= '2013-05-01')
     GROUP BY 
         OpportunityID) AS X 
INNER JOIN
    **BVSFWarehouse.dbo.sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY** AS H ON H.OpportunityID = X.OpportunityID 
                                                     AND X.MaxDate = H.CREATEDDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

`SSMS -> Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to `ALTER` the view before you have run the `CREATE`, are you?